# How can one draw polylines or curves in Google maps between two location but avoid drawing on land?

Tags: google-maps

As the question states, how can I draw a polyline or a curve between two points on a Google Map something like this:

[image]

but avoid drawing on any line between the two points.

I want to use this feature to draw dynamic cruise itineraries. Do not take into consideration very complicated routes, something simple.

For example assume I have this locations: Barcelona, Marseille, Nice, Genova, Napoli, Palermo and back to Barcelona.

If I draw straight lines it would look like this: http://prntscr.com/6eubrs
Instead I would like to achieve something like this: http://prntscr.com/6eucm9

Or is there a way to use/access the ferry routes and draw onto them?

Comment: You need the data for the land mass then buffer it by how far you want to be offshore.  You would find all matching points between your points based on the buffered area and draw a polyline along those points - this can be done by adding all the points to an array and creating a polyline using that as your path. Look at GeoJson library for managing your landmass data then adding it to a Google Maps Data layer. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#load_geojson More efficient way: get an API which gives your the shipping routes and use the spatial data from that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The problem is that commercial routes are very very different than cruises routes, plus I found some cruise routes that are very weird, like the stop near a small island that does not have commercial routes attached.

Comment: But, the idea of getting land mass data and buffer it sounds like a solution worth trying. I will try something and see if this works :)

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same task

Answer (score 1):

You could use OpenStreetMap and only import the ferry data with one of the [existing routing engines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing)

Comment: I just realized that ferry routes are not ok. If I have a cruise that sails from Barcelona to Napoli directly, the ferry route generated by Google or any other Maps api will have a few hops in different other locations, and this is not ok, since it will not draw the direct route I need it to.